# "Restore from Backup" iCloud and Ad-Hoc Apps

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ipad, restore, adhoc

I have posted this on the Apple support site but just seeing whether anyone can be of benefit here. We have a business iPad app which has been deployed to our users using the ad-hoc distribution method for trial purposes.

Their iPads are backed up using the iCloud automatic method and from what I gather our ad-hoc app (and data) is backed up using this method. Recently a user has deleted the app.

As part of the "Restore from Backup" process, all the AppStore apps are downloaded and installed as per normal, but with the ad-hoc apps they arnt restored at all. It just shows "Waiting ... and then Installing ..." and then it disappears. Im guessing its related to the fact the iPad cant redownloaded an ad-hoc app (it doesnt know where it came from), but how do we update the ad-hoc app on that device after a iPad Restore is done ?

Is there any way to get back the ad-hoc app and its data ?

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: Maybe just login with your apple ID at the new device - icloud should sync than all app data to the new device. When you install than the AdHoc App, the backuped data should be there.